# cannot find symbol .setOnRefreshListener android webview

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to add swipe to refresh on my webview using the below method but I can't get past the error, cannot find symbol setOnRefreshListener. What am I doing wrong?

```
 SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Insert annimation during refresh..
        w1.reload(); // refreshes the WebView
    }
});
```

Comment: What error do you get and where?

Comment: on the .setOnRefreshListener. Its just a red line saying cannot find symbol

Comment: Do you have `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"` in your gradle file?

Comment: No I dont. Lemmie give it a try.

Comment: Then add `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0"`

Comment: Still having the same problem:-(

Comment: Clean the project. From menu `Build -> Clean project`